# Включить js в другой js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, имеется скрипт(1)

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {

}
```

Как внутрь него не поместить другой скрипт , между скобок к примеру из папки ".src/js/js.js";

Comment: "**не** поместить" - ? Ничего **не** делать.

Comment: Не совсем понятный вопрос, заголовок такой "Включить js в другой js", а в объяснении "не поместить код".

Как я понял вам нужно поместить js файл на этот скрипт, если так, то может поместить этот скрипт на файл а файл тем временем импортировать в главный js?

Comment: если вы опечатались и вам нужно поместить, то пока поддержки в браузерах вроде как нет. Если вы используете сборку, то можно использовать модуль require

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятно что вы имеете в виду под "поместить внутрь него другой скрипт". Теги `<script>` не могут быть вложенными. Если вы просто хотите добавить скрипт в текущий документ используя Javascript, то это делается так же как и для любого другого DOM элемента: создаете новый элемент `<script>` методом [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 0):

Может у вас опечатка

> Как внутрь него **не** поместить другой скрипт

Но можете сделать в вашем скрипте `".src/js/js.js";` [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) чего либо:

```
export default function myFunction(data) {
  return data;
}

export const myConst = 'data';
```

а в файле где находится проверка, [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). К примеру:

```
import { myFunction, myConst } from "путь к файлу где мы делаем export"; 

if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
    myFunction();
}
```

Но если же это вопрос с подвохом то как написал [Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor)

> "**не** поместить" - ? Ничего **не** делать.