# Включить js в другой js из папки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, имеется скрипт(1)

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {

}
```

Как внутрь него поместить другой скрипт , между скобок , к примеру,из папки ".src/js/js.js";

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не надо задавать одинаковые вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766569

Comment: повтор вопроса.

Comment: @Igor, так репортите его!

Comment: @user263096 Когда я голосовал за закрытие этого вопроса, у дубликата еще не было ответа, поэтому я не мог выбрать "Возможный дубликат вопроса".

Comment: @Igor, согласен, не хватает пункта "Вы уже задавали этот вопрос"